# How to format the data (questions/answers) on stackoverflow mobile site?

Tags: support, code-formatting, formatting

Its very difficult to format the data while working on stackoverflow mobile site. Somehow I used to manage it via adding spaces for code etc. But when theres a large complex data to be posted it becomes difficult. Then I had to open it via browsers desktop site mode to enable that format editor on mobile device. Is this the only way to format data while working on mobile version?